# How to query a param in the middle of an URL with Retrofit

Tags: android, path, retrofit2, param

I'm reading post and docs about Retrofit 1 & 2. I have the next source code to get a repo from an user.

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<GithubRepo>> getRepos(@Path("user") String user);
```

In retrofit2 I see that now we need to change @Path with @Query, but I don't know if the using method is the same. It's like the next one or I need to change something more?

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<GithubRepo>> getRepos(@Query("user") String user);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

both are different @Query is used

when you have to assign some value in

> URL like www.xxx.com/user=name **(mostly @query is used to search the user details )**

we use like this ....

```
@GET("users/repos")
Call<List<GithubRepo>> getRepos(@Query("user") String user);
```

and @path is used when you change the path or URL or keyword of URL

> like www.xxx.com/sam ,www.xxx.com/sushan ,etc **(mostly @path is used to
>   fetch data of different user)**

we use like this ....

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<GithubRepo>> getRepos(@Path("user") String user); //here url changes with the value of String user
```

**NOTE:- @Query always come at end of the URL . And @Path is used anywhere in the URL**

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string  must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.I don't know then how to insert user id between users/.../repos

Comment: are you sure about `user` in middle of URL , MOST of time query placed end of URL ...... Will you please share the whole `RESTFUL API` .....

Comment: It's in the middle, is the github api

Comment: @MAOL use the 2nd method , which is with `@Path` .... it will work without any error .....

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters can also be added.

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);
```

Nothing must change.